# Implementation of AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have implemented AsyncTask like this in my code. Can you tell me if I used AsyncTask correctly? Thanks.

```
 protected  class AsyncTranslator extends AsyncTask<String, JSONObject, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


            String mymeaning = null;
            RestAPI api = new RestAPI();
            try
            {
                JSONObject jsonObj = api.GetMeaning(params[0]);
                mymeaning = jsonObj.toString();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("Error", e.getMessage());
            }
                        return mymeaning ;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            Toast.makeText(context, "Please wait.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String mymeaning) {
            Log.d("onPostExecute", null);
            Intent i = new Intent(SendMeaningActivity.this, ShowMeaningActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("meaning", mymeaning);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the question? I don't really see any..

Comment: yes, you used it correctly.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you used it correctly.

Fot API call, think to use library like [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). It will make your life easier.